# Value of the selected option is not saved in the collection aldeed:autoform-select2 Meteor

Tags: meteor, jquery-select2, meteor-autoform

I created a field of a schema (CollectionTest) as follows.

```
year: {
        type: String,
        label: "Year",
        autoform:{
            type:'select2',
            options:function () {

                return[{label:"2013",value:3102},{label:"2014",value:4102},{label:"2015",value:5102}]

            }
        }
    }
```

When I submit the autoform, it is inserted to the collection. But regardless of the selected option of the year, the year field is always saved as "2013" (which is not even a value).

```
collectionTest 
{
"_id" : "iysowN69pKWJeajDa",
"year" : "2013"
}
```

But when I change the 'select2' to 'select' it works fine. But I need to implement the 'select2' because the year field should be searchable.

And I imported following packages before implementing select2 field.

```
aldeed:autoform-select2
natestrauser:select2
```

Comment: I don't know about select2, but would you be interested in giving ```selectize``` a try? I currently have these three packages installed and they all work fine. ```chhib:selectize-bootstrap-3```, 
```vazco:universe-selectize```, 
```comerc:autoform-selectize```. Your Simple schema format mostly remains the same except you replace 'select2' with 'selectize'

Comment: @blueren That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. As this solved the issue it would be really helpful, if you can go on and put this as an answer :)

Comment: Great! I've also had issues with select2. So switched to an alternative becuase it's simply not worth investing more time into figuring out why it's notworking. I'll post the same as an answer for you to accept if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `select2`, but would you be interested in giving `selectize` a try?

I currently have these three packages installed and they all work fine.

```
chhib:selectize-bootstrap-3 
vazco:universe-selectize
comerc:autoform-selectize.
```

Your `Simple-schema` format mostly remains the same except you replace 'select2' with 'selectize'